# How to add header to xhr-request

Tags: cypress

I have the following scenario:

- A startpage that basically includes other pages through xhr-requests.
- Some of the xhr-requests are behind an firewall with a single-signon-scheme where each http-request to the server is stripped from a set of headers and then populated according to the users grants.
- When the request reaches the server it expect some of the reqeusts to have the userId-header.
- Test-servers are NOT behind "firewall" so we have a plugin in our browsers to emulate the behaviour.

  We would like to run cypress-tests on this page. But we doesn't seem
  to find how to add this userId-header to the xhr-requests and havn't
  been able to find an example of this behaviour.

  Could you please provide an example that shows how to do this with a simple example?

An attemt to pseduo-code the scenario: 
cy.visit('myurl').interceptBeforeXhr('xhr-url').addHeader('xhr-url', {'userId' = 'username'})

Comment: Have you try to bypass the firewall with an env variable `CYPRESS_INSTALL_BINARY=https://company.domain.com/cypress.zip npm install cypress`? Source: https://docs.cypress.io/guides/getting-started/installing-cypress.html#Install-binary

Comment: Doesn't my answer bellow cover your use case? If this doesn't work for you or you have any problems implementing it, you can state the problem so I can check it out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `headers` property to specify a header like this:

```js
describe('Test Cypress Custom Headers', function() {
  it('Visits Cypress Header Test Endpoint', function() {
    const Key = "test-key1";

    cy.visit({
      // An endpoint that expects a x-xhr-url header to grand access
      url: 'https://zikro.gr/dbg/so/59666650', 
      headers: {
        "x-xhr-url": Key
      }
    });

    cy.contains(`Access key: ${Key}`);
  })
});
```

Or you can use [`request`](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/request.html) if you want to make multiple requests using the same headers:

```js
describe('Test Cypress Custom Headers', function() {
  it('Visits Cypress Header Test Endpoint', function() {
    const Key = "test-key1";

    cy.request({
      url: 'https://zikro.gr/dbg/so/59666650',
      headers: {
        "x-xhr-url": Key
      }
    })
    .its('body').should('include', `Access key: ${Key}`);
  });
});
```

Both tests should be passing.

Just for the record, here is the PHP endpoint header check page code:

```php
$headers = getallheaders();

if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_XHR_URL'])) {
  echo "Access key: {$_SERVER['HTTP_X_XHR_URL']}";
} else {
  echo "Access denied";
}
```

Lastly, If you want to apply the header value just to all AJAX requests, then you shall use [`server`](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/server.html) `onAnyRequest` and there use `proxy` to set the `xhr` header like this:

```js
describe('Test Cypress Custom Headers', function() {
  it('Visits Cypress Header Test Endpoint', function() {
    const Key = "test-key1";

    cy.server({
      onAnyRequest: (route,  proxy) => {
        proxy.xhr.setRequestHeader('x-xhr-url', Key);
      }
    });

    cy.visit('https://zikro.gr/dbg/so/59666650/test-ajax.html');

    // Should pass the test of an AJAX call
    cy.contains(`Access key: ${Key}`);
  });
});
```

Comment: You should add the cy.request{... onHttpRequest(xhr){ }} to be complete. But very well invested 150 points. Thank you!